# PHAsset returned from fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs: is always nil when choosing a photo from the "My Photo Stream" album using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, phasset, photosframework

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` to let the user choose a photo or video to share in the app. When the user chooses a media item in their Library, I execute this code in one of the `UIImagePickerController's` delegate methods:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

PHAsset *asset;
if ([info[@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]) {
    // Video
    asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]] options:nil] lastObject];

} else if ([info[@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] isEqualToString:@"public.image"]) {
    // Photo
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]] options:nil];
    asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]] options:nil] lastObject];  
   }
}
```

Both `if statements` work fine for both photo and video, except for when you select an item from the album titled `"My Photo Stream"`.

When you select an item from `"My Photo Stream"`, the returned `PHAsset` is always `nil`.

I found the following question that appears to have an answer with a working solution: [ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL: always returning nil for photos in "My Photo Stream" in iOS 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480526/alassetslibrary-assetforurl-always-returning-nil-for-photos-in-my-photo-stream)

But the above link uses the `AssetsLibrary` framework which is no longer recommended by Apple:

> "In iOS 8.0 and later, use the Photos framework instead of the Assets
>   Library framework. The Photos framework provides more features and
>   better performance for working with a user’s photo library. See Photos
>   Framework Reference."

I need to be able to return `PHAsset` objects for the media items in the `"My Photo Stream"` album. Right now the reference URL that's returned by the `UIImagePickerController` in the `info` dictionary is a valid URL that logs in the console, but when using this URL, a valid `PHAsset` object is never returned.

Here is an example of a reference URL that is returned in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method's info dictionary:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=DCF5C6E5-B4F4-4E61-9C4B-CC63E104BF2B&ext=JPG
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug and seems to be fixed in the latest iOS 8.2x betas.

Comment: I have just update to IOS 8.2, unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: still seems to be a problem even with 8.4.1.

Comment: iOS 8.1 works but iOS 8.1.2 seems to return nil all the time

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 9.2.1, waiting to see 9.3 which was released yesterday.

Comment: I see this problem on iOS 9.3

Comment: same problem on 9.3 here :/

Comment: It's crazy man. Same problem on 10.3.3. How on earth could a bug persist since more than 2 years??

Answer (score 1):

It's unbelievable but as of iOS 10.3.3 the bug persists and it looks like it was fixed by only iOS 11...

In order to cover iOS 10 and below I'm using `fetchAssets` of `PHAsset` with info dictionary returned from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method:

```
PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as! URL], options: nil)
```

Remember that this returns an array of results.

Comment: Isn't your code the same as in the original question?